# Downloading Email Attachments with Python - When there's more than one attachment

Tags: python, win32com

I have code that searches through a group Outlook inbox based on a certain criteria and retrieves the date and time of emails satisfying the specified criteria. This code also downloads the first attachment in the email.

```
import win32com.client
from datetime import date, timedelta
import os


outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(18).Folders.Item("xxx")
messages = inbox.Items

path = os.path.expanduser("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents"
                          "\\Projects\\Python Projects\\Email Classification\\Email Attachments")


dateHigh = date.today() - timedelta(days=45)
dateLow = date.today() - timedelta(days=-0)
subject = "xxxxxxxx"

max = 100000
for count, message in enumerate(messages):
    if count > max:
        break
    if subject in message.subject and message.senton.date() > dateHigh and message.senton.date() < dateLow:
       print(message.senton.date())
       print(message.senton.time())
       print(message.subject)
       attachments = message.Attachments
       attachment = attachments.Item(1)
       for attachment in message.Attachments:
           if attachments.Count > 0:
               attachment.SaveASFile(path + '\\' + str(attachment))
           break
```

What I expected was for the email attachment (pdf/csv) files to be downloaded and stored, however, only images from the emails are being downloaded. How do I download other attached files in the email?

Comment: Why are you breaking out of the for loop after the first attachment?

Comment: I amended it to stay within the loop after the first attachment, however, it is still only downloading the image in the email as opposed to what is attached

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code in a python debugger. Do the attachments get saved?

```
import win32com.client
import os
from os.path import expanduser
home = expanduser("~")

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder("18")
all_inbox = inbox.Items

save_folder = os.path.join(home, "attach")
if not(os.path.exists(save_folder)):
    os.mkdir(save_folder)

for msg in all_inbox:
    print(msg.Subject)

    for att in msg.Attachments:
        print(att.FileName)
        print(msg.Attachments.Count)
        att.SaveASFile(os.path.join(save_folder, str(att.FileName)))
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your response. how would I go about doing this while still incorporating my criteria to search based on subject. And yes with my original code the attachments are getting saved. Sorry i'm very new to Python

Comment: Just add another if condition after ```print(att.FileName)```
 ```if subject in msg.subject and dateHigh > msg.senton.date() <= dateLow:```

Comment: hey thanks but this doesnt download anything at all